# K&R uninitialized integers?

Tags: c

> The standard library function strlen(s) returns the length of its
> character string argument s, excluding the terminal '\0'. Here is our
> version:
>
> ```
> /* strlen: return length of s */
> int strlen(char s[])
> {
>         int i;
>         while (s[i] != '\0')
>         ++i;
>         return i;
> }
> ```

This is from "The C Programming Language" book, why is `i` left uninitialized? The book mentioned that static and external variables are initialized to zero by default but it hasn't explained what static variables are at this point of the book and this clearly is not an external variable. Is it a static variable? I'm kinda confused.

Comment: Not sure about the original K&R C, but in any ANSI/ISO/Standard C version this code has undefined behavior, as `i` is indeed uninitialized and has an indeterminite value. `i` is neither static nor external. It is automatic.

Comment: This is from p39 (2nd ed). The original code there has an intervening `i = 0;`; ie this should be considered a typo. (Your snippet is clearly from the 2nd ed, but for everyone's information: The analogous code from the 1st ed on its p36 also has an intervening `i = 0;`.)

Comment: In my copy of K&R, there is `i = 0;` right after the declaration `int i;`.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question about some third-party source, give a bibliographic citation like you were taught to do in school, including title, authors, edition, and page number, at least.

Answer (score 4):

In K&R 2nd Edition (Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M Ritchie
[The C Programming Language, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) 1988), the index lists `strlen` on pages 39, 99 and 103.

The code on page 39 is:

```
/* strlen: return length of s */
int strlen(char s[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return i;
}
```

This code includes the line `i = 0;` which is missing from the question.

The code on page 99 is:

```
/* strlen: return length of string s */
int strlen(char *s)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

The code on page 103 is:

```
/* strlen: return length of string s */
int strlen(char *s)
{
    char *p = s;

    while (*p != '\0')
        p++;
    return p - s;
}
```

None of those exhibits undefined behaviour, and none of them is identical to the code quoted in the question. The code on p39 is closest, but it includes the crucial `i = 0;` that is missing from the quote in the question.

The code in K&R 2nd Edition is correct.  The quotation in the question is missing one (crucial) line.  (The analogous code in K&R 1st Edition (Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M Ritchie
[The C Programming Language, 1st Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131101633) 1978) is on pages 36, 95, 98 and uses the non-prototype, pre-standard coding conventions, but also contains the crucial `i = 0;` line on p36.  It, too, is correct.)

Note that the signature of `strlen()` in the book does not match the signature of `strlen()` in the Standard C Library (all editions C90 through C23):

```
extern size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

Comment: While scanning the code in K&R1, I noticed an interesting difference in the way that the `return` statement is documented and used (compared with K&R2).  In K&R1, it is introduced as **return(_expression_)** with parentheses, and it is used exclusively with parentheses.  In K&R2, it is introduced as **return _expression_** without parentheses, and it is generally used without parentheses.  Since I learned C from K&R1, I still have a tendency to parenthesize returned values; now I know why I do it like that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a static variable?

No.  It is an *automatic* variable.  That's the default for variables declared inside functions, and you can specify it explicitly for such variables via the `auto` keyword (but no one does).<sup>*</sup>  If it were static, you would be able to recognize that from the appearance of the `static` keyword in its declaration.

> I'm kinda confused.

Understandable.  The code presented in the question is flawed, for exactly the reason you ask about: the value of automatic variable `i` is used without that value having been initialized or previously assigned.  The resulting behavior is undefined, which is reasonably likely to manifest as miscalculations, hangs, and / or memory faults, though it doesn't *have* to do.

---

<sup>*</sup>In C23, `auto` has gained an additional significance for requesting type inference, and it has long had that significance in C++.  The spec has been worded so that valid historic uses of `auto`, if there were any, would still be valid, but you're unlikely to see it used in C code for anything but type inference.